# Implementing Search Bar in Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

This function is giving compile time error

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Compiler error at this line

```
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
```

ARC Semantic Issue

> No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector
>   'filterContentForSearchText:scope:'

How to remove this error ?
I am following this tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/) .  The exact function from the tutorial is giving error in xcode .

Answer (score 0):

Implement this

```
 - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
    {
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                        predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                        searchText];

        searchResults = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented it .The compile time error in function coded in question.

Comment: Refer https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: I am following this tutorial .The function searchDisplayController from the tutorial in giving error in xcode .

Comment: Exactly at which line the issue occurs..

Comment: [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString 
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

Comment: Implement the above method , which i posted and check whether its being called.